# how to assign value to a checked JChechbox?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am making a simple currency convertor which takes the initial value in a `JTextField` then the user clicks the `JCheckBox` corresponding to their desired currency, the converted value will then be displayed in another `JTextField`. Basically i would like to know is there any way of assigning a value to a  checked `JCheckBox`i have looked around and cannot find a clear answer to this, any help would be appreciated.

For example if the current conversion rate from Sterling to euro is 1.12244 this value would be assigned when the JCheckBox is checked, so the the original value would be multiplied by the conversion rate.

Comment: **assigning a value to a checked JCheckBox**? What do you mean by this? which kind of value do you want to assign? please elaborate.

Comment: or edit your post with code that's shows us what you are tried

Comment: Are you trying to make the JCheckBox "Checked"? or are you talking about assigning a certain value to that object (similar to Tags in Visual Studio)?

Comment: @Harry_Joy I guess @Darren_Burgess wants to ass gin the conversion value to the JCheckBox, in order to later do `result content=entered value*jcheckbox multiplier`. Unfortunatly, JCheckBox is **absolutely not** the widget for that. A [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) using for model currency names to their conversion rates would really better do the trick (as well in terms of features and in terms of UI, as it would result in `"an amount" converted into "a currency name"="a value"`)

Comment: @Riduidel that is exactly what i was hoping to do. I am aware i could do this using the JComboBox widget but was trying something different. At least i know it wont work before continuing further, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it'd be easier if you assign an `action-listener` to your `JCheckBox` and make the conversion on trigger of this event. To check is a `JCheckBox` is checked or not you can use the `isSelected()` method

**EDIT**

Actually i think you need to use `JRadioButton`'s in a `ButtonGroup` for this, as if you are using a checkbox then there is a chance that more than one is selected. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GetselectedbuttonfromButtonGroup.htm) is an example of how to do use ButtonGroup and trigger action on the radio button

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the value of the check box.

```
JCheckBox cb = ...;

// Determine status
boolean isSel = cb.isSelected();
if (isSel) {
    // The checkbox is now selected
} else {
    // The checkbox is now deselected
}
```

You can change the value on the action-listener of the JCheckBox

```
// Create an action
Action action = new AbstractAction("CheckBox Label") {
    // This method is called when the button is pressed
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Perform action
        JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox)evt.getSource();

        // Determine status
        boolean isSel = cb.isSelected();
        if (isSel) {
            // The checkbox is now selected
        } else {
            // The checkbox is now deselected
        }
    }
};

// Create the checkbox
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could not be the best solution but you can try this.

1. Take an array of JCheckBox.
2. Make sure only one checkbox gets selected at a time.
3. Take an array of currency conversion value.
4. Now based on the index of the selected checkbox get the currency conversion value from array.

Instead of using JCheckBox you can use JRadioButton as suggested by @Balanivash. More simpler and proper solution will be using JComboBox.[I'm with @Riduidel in this.]

Answer (score 1):

// this is whole working code i hope this this will help[image]

```
public class CConvertor extends JFrame {        

    private  JLabel result;
    private  JCheckBox pk;
    private  JCheckBox ch;

    public CConvertor(){

        result = new JLabel();
        ch = new JCheckBox();
        pk = new JCheckBox();
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        setTitle("JCheckBox Test");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(result);
        add(new JLabel("        "));        
        add(new JLabel(" China "));
        add(ch);
        add(new JLabel(" Pakistan "));
        add(pk);
        setSize(400,80);
        pk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ch.setSelected(false);
                result.setText("Pakistan selected");

            }
        });
        ch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pk.setSelected(false);
                result.setText("China is Selected");

            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CConvertor();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What it's easiest to do is something like this:

```
String[] ccys = {"USD", "EUR", "CHF", "JPY"};

public void initUI(){
 ...

 ButtonGroup grp = new ButtonGroup();

 for(String ccy : ccys){
  JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(ccy);
  cb.setActionCommand(ccy);
  cb.addActionListener(this);
  grp.add(cb);

  ...(add CheckBox to ui)
 }
}


private double getRate(String ccy){
  ...(retrieve the current conversion rate, f.ex from a map)
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
  Double rate = getRate(evt.getActionCommand());
  ...(calculation, display)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also think that JCheckBox isn't the best option to do what you want, however...

Why don't you extend the JCheckBox class to a CurrencyConverterCheckBox where you can
pass as arguments the currencies and the current value of the conversion.
e.g.:

```
    public class CurrencyConverterCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
       private String from;
       private String to;
       private double value;

       public CurrencyConverterCheckBox(String from, String to, double value) {
           super();
           this.from = from;
           this.to = to;
           this.value = value;
       }
    }
```

Then you will be able to do the conversion when the user clicks the checkbox. You can also provide labels next to the checkboxes (USD to EUR). And you can also provide a method in your new checkbox to flip the currencies and calculate the multiplication factor in the other direction.

kind regards